# Can't login using root account

Tags: command-line, login, tty

I have Ubuntu installed on VMware on the shell screen I couldn't login with the `Username: root` and `Password` I was asked to login with is there a way around this?

Comment: `root` is disabled by default in Ubuntu - see [RootSudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)

Answer (score 0):

Because of the `tty` tag you are using, I consider you just want to use `root` in `tty` and not GUI.

While installing you have created a regular user account which is able to use `sudo` command. in `tty` login using that user account. then to use root access for running commands use the `sudo` command:

```
sudo command-to-run
```

Remember when running `sudo`, it will asks for your account password, not root.

If you want to switch to root account you can also use `sudo`:

```
sudo -i
```

or

```
sudo -s
```

or even:

```
sudo su -
```

You can also select an specific shell to run, like this:

```
sudo -i /bin/zsh
```

#### Enabling root

If you want enable `root` account, so you are able to login using its credentials:

use one of above solutions to run `passwd` command to set a password for `root` account. E.g:

```
sudo passwd
```

then it will asks you for a new password. Also use `sudo passwd -u root` to make sure `root` account is unlocked now.

---

If you don't have any other user account to follow above instructions which is weired, use [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password#24024) solution to active your root account.